# How to get the actual program name using the PID of that running program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working on linux.

**Is there any way to get the user defined program name, given the PID of that running program?**

**I want to output the program name, not the process name.**

For example: I have a `java` application, named as *stackoverflow.java*. Now the process name will be decided by the system which can be different but the program name is *stackoverflow.java*. So the output should be the program name, given only the PID of that running program.

There are some commands which are fulfilling partial needs like:

**`cat /proc/"PID"/cmdline`** ->
This will give the command line arguments that creates that process with given "PID". But if we have various programs in different programming languages then the format of the command which runs that program will not be same. So in that case, how to extract the exact program name from this command?

**`readlink -f /proc/"PID"/exe`** -> This will give the executable file name related to the process with given "PID". But some processes do not have executable files. In that case, it will not return anything.

Actually I am working on very large scale. I want to find the application name (or source file name or program name) for all the processes that are running on the server. So I don't want to hard code anything specifically for any programming language like java, cpp, python etc. Please suggest me something generic in this regard.

Comment: You want to get the name of any _source files_ which may have been compiled to produce the running executable?

Comment: @user4556274 Yes exaclty, I want to find the name of the source file by using the PID of running executables.

Comment: You will need: `ps -q 3300 -o comm=`  where `3300` is your process ID

Comment: How do you define “program name”? There is no such technical concept. It's a phrase that you're using, but it has no standard meaning, so you need to define it.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry for inconvenience caused. By program name, I mean to say the source file's name which creates the process with given PID.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with a valid `<pid>`,

`/bin/cat /proc/<pid>/comm`

That would give the name of the executable.

`/bin/ls -lt /proc/<pid>/exe`

The above will give the path of the executable.

Comment: +1, but why `/bin/...`?

Comment: @pfnuesel, just not to get into the context of aliased (`alias`) commands.

Comment: ... and the result of this will be "java" - not what he is looking for methinks.

Comment: @MurrayJensen , right, and the command line arguments for `java` can be found from either doing a `cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline` or `cat /proc/<pid>/environ`

Comment: @saisasanka Thanks a lot for your efforts. Actually I am working on very large scale. I want to find the application name (or source file name or program name) for all the processes that are running on the server. So I don't want to hard code anything specifically for any programming language. Please suggest me something in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: @Aditya , to find the all processed running on a server, try `ps -eao cmd`

Comment: @saisasanka , *ps -eao cmd* is listing all the commands that create those processes. Is there anyway to get the source file name's from those commands? I know for system processes, we may not list the names. But for user related process we can.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to define a concept that just doesn't exist. You aren't going to find a general concept of “program name” or “application name” that goes beyond what you can find as the name of the executable.

The source file name**s** are not, in general, stored in the executable. For a script the “primary” source file name is the executable, but a script also uses code from a lot of other places (the interpreter at least). For a compiled program the information is not available at runtime unless something specific to the compiler or build chain puts it there, and most don't.

Looking at `/proc/$pid/exe` gives the path to the executable. All processes do have an executable¹. The executable may have been renamed or deleted since the process was started. That's the only universal concept of “program name”.

The first element of `/proc/$pid/cmdline` is argument 0 passed when invoking the process. This name is chosen by the caller of the process. Unless the caller went out of its way, this is normally the base name of the executable, with or without a directory part depending on whether the program was invoked through a PATH lookup. A process can overwrite this part but few programs do (mostly, a few daemons do this to reflect their status in a way that can easily be seen with `ps`).

Linux also stores a process name that's reported by `ps -o comm`. It's accessible through `/proc/$pid/status`. That's the initial base name of the executable, truncated to 16 bytes.

¹  <sub>There are entries in `/proc` whose `exe` link is not readable. Those are kernel threads or zombies, not processes. For all processes, the link is readable (with proper permission), though it might not point to an existing file if the executable has been deleted.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Now I got the concept. Actually when I am executing the command: */proc/$pid/cmdline* on the server, then it is listing out some services running on that server. I want to get the service names. Is there any way to get that? Currently I am trying by looking at the .xml file that I am getting from the command line arguments in **/proc/$pid/cmdline** command. But challenge is to write the generic code that lists out the service names.

Comment: @Aditya Define “service name”...

Comment: Service name means name of tomcat services.

Comment: @Aditya Ok, “tomcat service” has a precise definition, I think. I have no idea how they work, though. Please ask a new question specifically about tomcat services.

Comment: Ok I will put more clear question now. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no general solution for this,
because it is not always possible. 
If I have a C program, `blue.c`, and I compile it with

```
cc blue.c -o green
```

and then run the `green` executable,
there will be no way to determine that the source name was `blue.c`,
short of forensic measures like searching my directory. 
(This statement is true for at least some C compilers.)